# Calling a C function from swift in background

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

My task here is to call a function that is written in C from main.swift. But this call needs to execute in the background (asynchronously) as it takes a few minutes.
trialFunc() takes around 30-45 minutes to finish doing the op. Running it on main thread gives me 0x8badf00d error. And when I try to run it in background, looks like control reaches end of execution.

My main.swift is shown below:

```
import Foundation

//let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Background thread", qos:.background);
//dispatchQueue.async {
//    trialFunc();             <-- This does not run
//    print("Inside async");   
//};

trialFunc();   <-- This works but runs on main thread
```

Contents of my bridging header:

```
#include "callIntoC.h"
```

Contents of callIntoC.h shown below:

```
#ifndef callIntoC_h
#define callIntoC_h

void trialFunc(void);
#endif /* callIntoC_h */
```

Contents of callIntoC.c

```
#include "callIntoC.h"
#include "app/call_main.h"

void trialFunc()
{
    my_main();   <-- This calls into the C code which does all my network I/O op
    return;
}
```

How can I make my trialFunc() run in the background thread when called from main.swift? I'm new to iOS dev, any help is appreciated. TIA...

Update: I tried to print something in main.swift after all the async related code. The print message get displayed. Only the code within async block isn't executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not run" when you try to call `trialFunc()` from a background queue? Are you sure the problem isn't simply the app reaching the end of main immediately due to the async call?

Comment: @rmaddy: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure how to check if app has reached end of main due to async call. How can I make sure the async block gets executed?
I put a print before calling trialFunc() to check if at least the control gets into the block. The print message never got displayed on the console.

Comment: Traditional discussions of running code in a background thread is geared towards apps that have a UI (where the main thread services the UI). But for a command line app, there’s no need to push stuff to a background thread, since you have no UI that you need to support while the computation is in progress. The easiest solution is to simply not try to run `trialFunc` on background thread. Now, if you do need to have some interaction with the app while `trialFunc` is running, that’s a separate question, but doesn’t seem relevant here...

Comment: ... so, when you say “this call needs to execute in the background”, perhaps you can describe why you think it needs to do that. Is it because you’ve seen the standard “don’t run time-consuming code on the main thread” advice (which is critical when your app has to simultaneously service a UI while the code runs, but is not relevant for most command line apps)? Or is there some other reason you want to run this on a background thread?

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to run trialFunc() in the background is because if I run it on the main thread, I get EXC_CRASH(SIGKILL) error in crash log. The error code is 0x8badf00d. This link says the task needs to run on a different thread: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1693/_index.html

Comment: trailFunc() does network related IO which is why I think it cannot be run on main thread...